# Android route on mapview with two points

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to draw actual route on mapview. I have tried examples but all seem to draw a line between two points not a route. I have used below code but it will automatically draw a route.

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(String.valueOf(urlString)));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
```

I want to draw a route with my own way points in map view.

Comment: Try this: [example1][1],[example2][2] Might it will help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243146/i-want-to-draw-path-between-multiple-geopoins-in-android
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408671/android-draw-route-on-a-mapview-with-twoo-poi-s

Comment: @Imran I have seen this but not works for me.